# Prevent relay from fast switching at the edge of the open voltage

Tags: battery-charging, indicator

I built an indication circuit to detect when the battery is fully charged and when it is charging.

[image]

The circuit is located between the battery charger and the battery. When the charging voltage reaches 14 V, the Zener diode starts to conduct and the BC547 switches the 12V relay. The problem is that relay starts switching fast ON and OFF at the edge of the open voltage when the Zener diode starts conducting. How can I prevent that?

Comment: You need to add hysteresis to your circuit.

Comment: What is the simplest way to do ?

Answer (score 4):

A very simple modification would be to use a set of the relay contacts to turn the relay into a latching relay.

Comment: I don't know why this received a downvote because it sounds a plausible solution given the limited scope in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To add hysteresis:

Put 2.7 k in series with the top of the zener. This will increase  the trip point by about 0.7*2.7k/10k, or 200 mV

Add a PNP transistor: E = battery, base via 10 kΩ to the NPN's collector and PNP's collector to the junction of the 2k7 and the zener.

This will give about 200 mV of hysteresis. Adjust the 2k7 to suit.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the BC547 datasheet it seems that your 0.7 voltage bias when zener is working and Vbat = 14.7V is very close to Vbe(th), so that the transistor will oscillate btw open/close state. Also, when Vbat is just above 14V, Vbe will be very small and there will be no commutation. It will not solve the problem ... but zener diodes have small dynamic resistor so that the zener voltage strongly depends on current variation at output. Perhaps reducing the 10k resistor would allow a greater current to flow through the zener, thus increasing the Vbe stability. In your current configuration when Vbat = 14.7V, the zener current is only about 0.7/10k = 70uA. Depending on the zener diode you chose, recommended Iz will be around 1mA.

Answer (score -1):

To prevent the oscillation at the switch point you need to introduce hysteresis, which is created by positive feedback. We can get that from the other side of the relay.

In the circuit below the Zener has been replaced with a resistor R1, and there’s a positive feedback path from the normally-closed relay in the form of R2 being connected in parallel to the 10K, making it smaller.

When battery voltage rises to the point where the transistor turns on (base about 0.6V) the relay switches and R2 is no longer in the circuit, and this causes the base voltage to rise farther (positive feedback).

The LED turns on using the only side of the relay.

The circuit is now latched and won’t unlatch until the battery voltage falls low enough for the transistor to turn off, but if your charger is always plugged in this is not a case you care about.

With R1 = R2 = 220K I think you’ll be close to your design goals but some tweaking may be in order.

[image]

Comment: This would require that the relay is SPDT, and the wiper is grounded. Also, the trip point depends on the VBE of a transistor, and this changes significantly with temperature. With R1==220k, there won't be enough base drive for the NPN.

Comment: Right, the resistors levels should all be reduced. The relay is drawn as a SPDT so that's what I assumed.